# Vertically concatenate part of cell contents

Tags: arrays, matlab, select, concatenation, cell-array

In MatLab, all cells in my 60x1-cellarray contain a 10x1 double.

I would like to concatenate all these doubles vertically, except for the first number in every double.

My failed attempts was:

```
CellArray={[1 2 3];[1 2 3];[1 2 3]}
ContacenatedCellArray = vertcat(CellArray{:,1}(2:end))
```

This, obviously, did not work becauce `CellArray{:,1}` refers to multiple cells so that `(2:end)` is a bit silly.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just do it in two lines:

```
temp = vertcat(CellArray{:}); %// or cell2mat(CellArray)
temp2 = temp(:,2:end)';
ContacenatedCellArray = temp2(:);
```

Comment: This results in `[2 3; 2 3; 2 3]` and I was looking for `[2 ; 3 ; 2 ;3 ;2 ;3]`. Sorry, I was not clear

Comment: @user3410778 That was not clear from your question. See my edit for that solution.

Comment: Lesson learned. I should not only explain the problem but also make clear what the desired output is :-)
Thanks for solving my problem twice!

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
%%// Vertically concatenated array
ContacenatedCellArray = cell2mat(CellArray); 

%%// Use the first index of every double array to remove those
ContacenatedCellArray(1:10:end)=[];
```

Comment: This results in `[1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 ]`. Or did I do it wrong?

Comment: @user3410778 the `10` is for your actual data, for you sample data use `3`.You will still have to transpose after this.

Comment: That was dumb.... Sorry. Now I notice that this is the same solution as I came up with as a workaround. Another lesson learned, look at the solution first before pasting it in MatLab to see if it works.

This whole stackoverflow thing is not as easy as I thought...

Answer (score 2):

Okay. I found a workaround. Just delete that first double after contacenating everything. Not pretty but it works...

`ContacenatedCellArray(1:length(CellArray{1,1}):end)=[];`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is this one-line solution where selection is done before concatenation

```
cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) x{1}(2:end), CellArray, 'UniformOutput', 0))
```

Input & output

```
CellArray={(1:4)';(1:4)';(1:4)'}

ans =

     2
     3
     4
     2
     3
     4
     2
     3
     4
```

Comment: This works for your CellArray but not for mine... Yours is `{[1;2;3;4][1;2;3;4]}` whereas mine was `{[1 2 3] ;[1 2 3]}`

Comment: I take the point. But there is a row/column mismatch between the text `contain a 10x1 double` of the question and the example `[1 2 3]`